# Stop Visual Studio 2010 from Spamming My Documents

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

I have Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express edition, and every time I open it it makes a new folder in My Documents. Problem is, I want to reserve My Documents for, you know, actual documents. I managed to redirect most of the stuff in the folder into another place by changing the settings, but a folder called StartPages stays, no matter what. After some research I found I have to change something in the registry, which I can't seem to find. I researched into that and apparently I need to create a new Setup Project or something, which I also can't seem to find. I have no idea what I'm doing at the moment, so any advice would be appreciated.

(I have a bit of OCD when it comes to organizing my files the way I want, so if I can't get this to work I might go crazy). Thank you.

Comment: Can you create a setup project in VS 2010 Express?

Comment: @Brian - no, I don't think that VS 2010 Express Edition includes the ability to create installs.  However, I don't think that's going to help here anyway.

Comment: I don't know, to be honest. I had the 2012 Professional edition before, becuase I got it free with my .edu email address, but I had to remove it because it didn't work with XNA. I really just want this stupid program to stop spamming My Documents so I don't have to make a non-official documents folder again

Comment: Look at the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0 registry key.  Make a backup before you mess with these keys.

Comment: @HansPassant I would love to, but I have no idea what a registry key is or how to go about opening this registry.

Comment: If you want to master the machine then that's pretty essential knowledge.  I'm sure it can wait until you learn more about it.  Lots of resources available, start by googling "registry key".  Avoid searching for "spamming", that means something very different :)

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, I googled it, but it seems quite complicated. I'm really just interested in fixing this problem now so I can restore order to my now-chaotic organization system. I'll definitely try to look into it in the future, though.

Comment: @user2472899 The registry is an important part of Windows.  As Hans says, it's pretty essential knowledge.  To find the thing you're looking for, run the program `RegEdit`, hit `Ctrl+F` to invoke the find dialog, type `VisualStudioLocation` into the search box, choose only the `Values` option and hit find.  One of the keys (folders) that contains that value is the one you want - check the path of the key to make sure it's referring to Visual Studio, not SQL Server Management Studio or anything similar.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Options in the Tools menu, select the `Projects and Solutions -> General` option group.  The top item in that group of options should be the default project location.  Change that to wherever you want your projects to go by default.

You might also need to change the other two directories in that option group.

This is based on VS2010 Pro version.  If it's not there in Express, let me know and I'll have another look at it.

--

Except you've already done that.  Sorry, wasn't paying attention as well as I should be.

If you can't find the registry entry to change, you could try turning off the Start Page completely.  Personally I've never found it useful, so I turned it off shortly after installing VS2010.

In `Tools->Options->Environment->Startup` change the `At startup` option to `Show empty environment`.  This disables the Start Page functionality, which also stops VS from executing the code that is creating the `StartPages` folder.

The registry path for Express editions is different to the Pro edition, and I don't have a VS2010 Express installed here at the moment to look at.  Try searching for the value `VisualStudioLocation` in RegEdit, and change any value in that registry key that uses `%USERPROFILE%\Documents` to point to somewhere else.

Comment: I did that already. It moved most of the folders to the directory I chose, but the StartPages folder is still created every time I open or close visual studio.

Comment: Changing to empty startup didn't seem to work, as it still made the file. I'd like to try that next part, but I'm still not quite sure how to open up RegEdit, or any kind of registry thing. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @user2472899 See my comment above.

Comment: Ok, thank you Cory and everyone else. That was a lot simpler than it seemed. I'm searching for it now.